# How to make gvim main window not quit when I type `:q` or `:qa`?

Tags: vim

Instead I want it to close the files and open the default `No Name` buffer. I sometimes accidentally close the last file and I have to restart gvim and cd to the proper directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put it in your $MYVIMRC

```
function! NumberOfWindows()
  let i = 1
  while winbufnr(i) != -1
  let i = i+1
  endwhile
  return i - 1
endfunction


function! DonotQuitLastWindow()
  if NumberOfWindows() != 1
    let v:errmsg = ""
    silent! quit
    if v:errmsg != ""
        "echohl ErrorMsg | echomsg v:errmsg | echohl NONE
        "echoerr v:errmsg
        echohl ErrorMsg | echo v:errmsg | echohl NONE
    endif
  else
     echohl Error | echo "Can't quit the last window..." | echohl None
  endif
endfunction

if has("gui_running")
    cnoreabbrev <expr> q getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'q' ? 'call DonotQuitLastWindow()' : 'q'
    cnoreabbrev <expr> qa getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'qa' ? 'call DonotQuitLastWindow()' : 'qa'
endif
```

Comment: nice one, and seems safe (getcmdline() call). Now, :qa will still exit, but not q.

Comment: `DonotQuitLastWindow` will only close one window… add an argument to it and make it a loop (`while NumberOfWindows() != 1`) if was triggered by `qa`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `:close` command instead, that command won't close the last window.

Comment: `<c-w><c-c>` might be a bit shorter. :)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use

```
:bd
```

to close the buffer (after you saved the latest changes)?